# Swift "-" Binary Operator on CollectionTypes

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to remove objects in array only if that objects are contained in another array.

```
myArray = myArray - otherArray
```

How can I add this behavior as an extension to CollectionType

Comment: Why do you want to write it for all collection types when you specifically mention the ability to do it with arrays?

Comment: @MikeAtNobel, one reason is to avoid duplicate code - what if he wants to do the same thing with a dictionary later, for example.

Comment: But to me, determining an object's presence in an array vs. a dictionary are two separate operations. An object may be present in the key of a dictionary, for example, but not have the same corresponding value for the key. So, I was just asking what the reason might be to create one blanket function for all types, if it is only needed for arrays.

Comment: Exactly what ABakerSmith said. Look up WWDC 2015 video on Swift Protocol Oriented Programming

Comment: Wow! Mind blown. Thanks for that reference. Truly a great talk. And in light of it, I retract my previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do it a couple ways. I've required the elements to be hashable in these versions, but the method would be similar (if much slower) for them just to be equatable.

If your collection conforms to `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`, then it has the `removeAtIndex` method available to it. This means that you can return a collection the same type as the one given:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
  mutating func subtractInPlace(vals: Set<Generator.Element>) {
    // The indices need to be reversed, because removing at a given index invalidates all
    // those above it
    for idx in indices.reverse()
      where vals.contains(self[idx]) { // This is why hashable is a requirement: the 
      removeAtIndex(idx)               // contains method is much more efficient on sets
    }
  }
  mutating func subtractInPlace<
    S : SequenceType where
    S.Generator.Element == Generator.Element
    >(seq: S) {
      subtractInPlace(Set(seq))
  }
  func subtract(vals: Set<Generator.Element>) -> Self {
    var col = self
    col.subtractInPlace(vals)
    return col
  }
  func subtract<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Generator.Element>(seq: S) -> Self {
    return subtract(Set(seq))
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll just return an array. (actually, I think this method is faster)

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
  func subtract(vals: Set<Generator.Element>) -> [Generator.Element] {
    return filter { !vals.contains($0) }
  }
  func subtract<
    S : SequenceType where
    S.Generator.Element == Generator.Element
    >(seq: S) -> [Generator.Element] {
      return subtract(Set(seq))
  }
}
```

Then, you need to define the operators. The reason there are so many different versions here is that Swift will select the most specific implementation in each case. So the version with a set will be selected before the version that converts to a set. This allows you to have an efficient implementation, without invalidating other, less efficient implementations.

```
func - <
  C : RangeReplaceableCollectionType where
  C.Generator.Element : Hashable
  >(lhs: C, rhs: Set<C.Generator.Element>) -> C {
    return lhs.subtract(rhs)
}

func - <
  C : RangeReplaceableCollectionType,
  S : SequenceType, T : Hashable where
  C.Generator.Element == T,
  S.Generator.Element == T
  >(lhs: C, rhs: S) -> C {
    return lhs.subtract(rhs)
}

func - <
  S : SequenceType where
  S.Generator.Element : Hashable
  >(lhs: S, rhs: Set<S.Generator.Element>) -> [S.Generator.Element] {
    return lhs.subtract(rhs)
}

func - <
  S0 : SequenceType,
  S1 : SequenceType,
  T : Hashable where
  S0.Generator.Element == T,
  S1.Generator.Element == T
  >(lhs: S0, rhs: S1) -> [T] {
    return lhs.subtract(rhs)
}
```

Comment: Nice. But with some explaining comments it would be even more useful for other readers ...

Comment: Doing it now! I had to run off for a minute.

Comment: What if you try to subtract `[2, 4]` from `[2, 2, 4]`? Would you expect the first 2 to remain?

Answer (score -1):

Just write a global function "func -" with two operands. Try doing it as a generic function.

Comment: Why would he want to write it as a global function instead of as an extension as he suggested?